# SQL statement to find a key that doesn't contain a row with a value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that has multiple rows per key (employee #) as shown below. I'm trying to find keys that do have particular skills across their set of rows.

I need help to write an Access SQL query that only identifies employees that do have Project Management and Speaking skill records. I don't care if they do have a Coding record.

```
Employee #       Skill
5261            Coding
8328            Coding
8328            Speaking
8328            Project Management
```

Employee 5261 should be excluded in the output because that employee does not have a Project Management and Speaking skill listed.
Employee 8328 should be included in the output because that employee has Project Management and Speaking skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query for the desired output

```
SELECT [Employee #] as Employee, count(*) AS cnt
FROM sourcetable
WHERE skill IN ('Speaking', 'Project Management')
GROUP BY [Employee #]
HAVING cnt > 1
```

Comment: This looks good, I'm going to test it in a bit and then accept it if it works but logically, it looks good.

Comment: @Jazzmine..the second query here would give you the wrong result. You should go with MarcB's solution.

Answer (score 2):

just do a basic `where` filter for both skills, but count how many of the skills the person has, and filter on that count:

```
SELECT [Employee #], count(*) AS cnt
FROM yourtable
WHERE Skill IN ('Speaking', 'Project Management')
GROUP BY [Employee #]
HAVING cnt = 2
```